# Update location of sprite between functions

Tags: c++, sfml

Im am trying to make a clean and organized way of making sprites. The problem is that the position of the sprites are being read as zero and they are just being drawn in the top left corner.

Sprite.h

```
#ifndef Sprite_h
#define Sprite_h


#endif /* Sprite_h */

using namespace std;
bool show = true;
class Sprite{
public:
    int Spritex;
    int Spritey;
    string name;
    sf::Texture texture;

    Sprite(string image, int x, int y){
        x = Spritex;
        y = Spritey;
        texture.loadFromFile(image);
    }
    sf::Sprite getSprite() {
        sf::Sprite sprite;
        sprite.setTexture(texture);
        sprite.setPosition(Spritex, Spritey);
        return sprite;

    }

    void changeimage(string image);


};

void Sprite:: changeimage(string image){
    texture.loadFromFile(image);

}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "Character.h"
#include "Projectile.h"
#include "Sprite.h"

//Use std
using namespace std;
//Boolean to determine if screen will scroll
bool scroll = false;

//player that is part of Character class and computer that is part of Sprite class
Character player("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Sprites/Player.png");
Sprite computer("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Sprites/CompSprite.png", 1200, 100);
Sprite battery("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Sprites/battery4.png", 0, 0);

//boolean for whether to show weapon or not
bool showweapon;
//main loop
int main() {
    int windowWidth = 5000;//width of window
    int windowHeight = 5000;//height of window
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(windowWidth, windowHeight ), "Awesome Game" );//Make the window

    //Setting up the dungeon back-round
    sf::Texture dungeon;
    dungeon.loadFromFile("/Users/danielrailic/Desktop/Xcode /NewGame/ExternalLibs/Sprites/DungeonBack.png");
    sf::Sprite backround;
    backround.setTexture(dungeon);

    while (window.isOpen()){

        // check all the window's events that were triggered since the last iteration of the loop
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event)){
            // "close requested" event: we close the window
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        //Movement
        if (moveChar == true){

            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left)){
                player.left();
                }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right)){
                player.right();
                }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up)){
                player.forward();
                }
            if (sf:: Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down)){
                player.backward();
                }
            if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::LShift))
            {
                player.Highspeed();
            }
            else{
                player.Lowspeed();
            }
        }
        //If player intersects with comp sprite, pick up comp sprite
        if (player.getSprite().getGlobalBounds().intersects(computer.getSprite().getGlobalBounds())){
            show = false;
            player.hascomp = true;
        }
        //draw and window stuff
        window.clear(sf::Color(255, 255, 255));
        window.draw(backround);
        if (show == true){
            window.draw(computer.getSprite());
        }
        if (show == false){
            window.draw(battery.getSprite());
        }
        window.draw(player.getSprite());
        window.display();
        window.setFramerateLimit(70);

        }
    }
```

If you have a question I will do my best to answer. Everything works except the spritex and spritey are being read as 0 for some reason. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just to note, you should probably make your sprite a private member of your class, remove the `getSprite()` member, and derive the class from `sf::Drawable`. This way you can just call `window.draw(player)` *without* creating a new sprite object every time your player is drawn.

Comment: Alright i'm going to look into that, I am pretty new to c++ so thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing to variables `x` and `y` here, which you never read from:

```
Sprite(string image, int x, int y){
    x = Spritex;
    y = Spritey;
    texture.loadFromFile(image);
}
```

I assume you flipped the assignments, and should write

```
Sprite(string image, int x, int y){
    Spritex = x;
    Spritey = y;
}
```

or

```
Sprite(string image, int x, int y) : Spritex(x), Spritey(y) {
    texture.loadFromFile(image);
}
```

If you turn up your warning levels, you will be warned about things like this, and also the non-initialized member you still have (`name`)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot, I can't believe I overlooked that, I flipped the x and y with the Spritex and Spritey, that did the trick. Thanks!